# windows xp command prompt remote

Tags: windows-xp, networking, remote-desktop, java, command-line

I was wondering if it was possible to have remote access to a command prompt on a windows xp machine, like using remote desktop services, only with the command prompt. I'm programming a java application, and having a full remote desktop service is a kind of a system hog. Also, the system I am using to access windows remotely is ubuntu. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your on the same local network and behind a router, you can install the telnet server on windows xp under "add remove programs" and then on the left there should be a button to add or remove windows components. I think you need your windows installation cd to install it. There are also third party telnet servers that you can install on windows XP.

Telnet is however not a secure protocol. Authentication is done in plain text. This telnet server is not something you'd want to put out on the Internet. It might be ok if it were done over a vpn...

SSH is the same concept as telnet... except on steroids. SSH traffic is encrypted. Windows does not provide an SSH server option as far as I know. Cygwin does a good job though. I would feel better putting an ssh server out on the internet... but it is still a security risk. You'd want a very strong password and a program that blocks IP's if there have been too many failed connection attempts. This would also ideally be done over a VPN if it is not internal to your network.